# [ solver } Sort gallery By date

Tags: php, arrays, date, sorting, gallery

I have a problem, I created a gallery it works perfectly but The function which sort the images depends on they DAY only it ignores the mouths and minutes ... 
The form used for the sort is :::::   | **d/m/Y H:i:s** |, but when I move to another mouth I lose the order because it depends only on the day as I said I want it to take in consideration the mouth too.

```
$date = date ("d/m/Y H:i:s",filemtime($dir_mini));

function sortFunctionASC ( $a , $b ) { return strcmp($a["date"], $b["date"]); }
```

And here I give the part which sort the gallery

```
//Boucle sur le répertoire On extrait aussi le Nom de l'image et de la miniature 
    $images = array();
    while ( false !== ($Fichier = readdir($ouverture))) 
    {       
            $berk = array('.', '..');

            $dir_mini = $dos_mini.$Fichier;
            $dir_img  = $dos_img.$Fichier;
            $img_name = $dir_mini ; 
            $img_name = preg_replace('#jpg|png|jpg|mini|/|\.#i', '',$img_name);
            $date_precise = date ("d/F/Y-H:i",filemtime($dir_mini));
            $date = date ("d/m/Y H:i:s",filemtime($dir_mini));  
            if(!in_array($Fichier, $berk) AND !is_dir($dir_mini) AND !is_dir($dir_img) )

            {
                $image = array();
                $image['date_precise']  = $date_precise;
                $image['date']  = $date;
                $image['img']   = $dir_img;
                $image['thumb'] = $dir_mini;
                $images[] = $image;

            }   
    }   
    closedir($ouverture);   

// Cette deux fonctions trient les images en fonction de date  ASC croissant, DESC décroissant 
function sortFunctionASC ( $a , $b ) { return strcmp($a["date"], $b["date"]); }
function sortFunctionDESC( $b , $a ) { return strcmp($a["date"], $b["date"]); }

if (isset ($_GET['ASC']))  { usort ($images,"sortFunctionASC"); }
if (isset ($_GET['DESC'])) { usort ($images,"sortFunctionDESC"); }
if (!isset($_GET['ASC']) AND !isset($_GET['DESC'])) { usort ($images,"sortFunctionDESC") ;}
```

Comment: Use a timestamp for sorting as that will always be consistent as string sort on DMY will always provide inconsistent results as it sees the day as more important than the month which is more important than the year.

Comment: Well I solved my problem i just Changed the Date to y-m-d thanks anyway =D

Comment: That would work, but it would still be much simpler and quicker to just sort by the timestamp, rather than converting the timestamp from filemtime into a date then doing a text sort on the date

Answer (score 0):

i think you should convert the date to timestamp for sorting. so simple use filemtime ( string $filename ) without the date ("d/m/Y H:i:s"... stuff

```
function sortFunctionASC ( $a , $b ) { return $a["stamp"] < $b["stamp"]); }
function sortFunctionDESC( $b , $a ) { return $a["stamp"] < $b["stamp"]); }
```